# jquery problem with code

Tags: jquery

This code

```
   function get_players()
{
    $.ajax({   
    type:   "POST",
    url:    "get_players.php",   
    dataType: "html",  
    success:  function(data) {
        var str = data;
                var chars = str.split("<br />");
                var lol = chars.length;
                for(var i = lol; i--; ) {
                    chars[i] = chars[i].split('/');
                    var o = document.getElementById(chars[i][0]);
                    if (!o) {
                        var aimt = i;
                        if (aimt!=chars.length-1 && aimt != 0) {
                            $('#gracze').html('<div id="'+chars[aimt][0]+'" class="char"></div>'+$('#gracze').html());
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).position.left = chars[aimt][1];
                        $('#'+chars[aimt][0]).position.top = chars[aimt][2];
                    }
                }
        }});
    setTimeout("get_players();", 2500);
}
```

Outputs me in js console pls hlp :(

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

Comment: post more code. what is aimt?

Comment: It looks as if chars[aimt][0] is empty.

Comment: What is the value of data when this occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery throws *"uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #"* when you use an empty id selector, for example:

```
$('#'); //throws: "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #"
```

So, the problem with your pasted snippet is that `chars[aimt][0]` is returning an empty string, which is causing `$('#'+chars[aimt][0])` to throw an exception.

Comment: That's pretty stupid that jQuery can't throw its own error and instead a *syntax error* happens. There's no syntax error here. Not very helpful.

Comment: @apphacker It *is* jQuery's error, and it *is* basically a syntax error. If you look at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js, you'll notice the line `throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg;`.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the place where your problem is, there's nothing wrong with the code you pasted. There's probably a missing ' somewhere else in your code above this part and your code is not closing the string properly until it sees the next ', the following character being the # which is a syntax error.

Looking at your updated code I don't see any syntax errors. Did you fix it?

Comment: No it isn't. I explained why. You have an unclosed string somewhere else.